# Python Implementation of Logistic Regression as Regression (Not Classification!)

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I have a regression problem on which I want to use logistic regression - not logistic classification - because my target variables `y` are continuopus quantities between 0 and 1. However, the common implementations of logistic regression in Python seem to be exclusively logistic classification. I've also looked at GLM implementations and none seem to have implemented a sigmoid link function. Can someone point me in the direction of a Python implementation of logistic regression as a regression algorithm.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887904/how-can-i-use-logistic-regression-in-sklearn-for-continuous-but-bounded-dependen

Comment: This post is exactly my question, and the answers aren't helpful. Logistic Regression is a regression model - people might use it for classification, but here, I want to use it as a regression model.

Comment: You could use sklearn logistic regression and use `predict_proba(X)` as your prediction for Y

Comment: sklearn refuses to fit logistic regression if the target variables are not discrete classes. My targets are not discrete classes.

Comment: The popular sentiment that logistic regression "should be used" for classification problems only is frustrating.  There is never any reason given for this, and there are plenty of systems on which you may wish to fit a sigmoid.  Future readers be advised that this a dogmatic stance that does not pervade other fields

Comment: In statsmodel. both GLM with family Binomial and discrete model Logit allow for  a continuous target variable as long as the values are restricted to interval [0, 1]. Similarly.  Poisson is very useful to model non-negative valued continuous data.

Comment: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2040 QMLE

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer For what obejective do you want to optimize it? PyTorch's binary cross entropy expects continuous target.

Comment: I want to use a GLM library so I can have a nice summary of parameters, their p-values and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In statsmodels both GLM with family Binomial and discrete model Logit allow for a continuous target variable as long as the values are restricted to interval [0, 1].

Similarly, Poisson is very useful to model non-negative valued continuous data.

In these cases, the model is estimated by quasi maximum likelihood, QMLE, and not by MLE, because the distributional assumptions are not correct. Nevertheless, we can correctly (consistently) estimate the mean function. Inference needs to be based on misspecification robust standard errors which are available as `fit` option `cov_type="HC0"`

Here is a notebook with example
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/quasibinomial.html

some issues with background for QMLE and fractional Logit
https://www.github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2040 QMLE
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2712

Reference

Papke, L.E. and Wooldridge, J.M. (1996), Econometric methods for fractional response variables with an application to 401(k) plan participation rates. J. Appl. Econ., 11: 619-632. https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1099-1255(199611)11:6<619::AID-JAE418>3.0.CO;2-1

**update and Warning**

as of statsmodels 0.12

Investigating this some more, I found that discrete Probit does not support continuous interval data. It uses a computational shortcut that assumes that the values of the dependent variable are either 0 or 1. However, it does not raise an exception in this case.
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7210

Discrete Logit works correctly for continuous data with optimization method "newton". The loglikelihood function itself uses a similar computational shortcut as Probit, but not the derivatives and other parts of Logit.

GLM-Binomial is designed for interval data and has no problems with it. The only numerical precision problems are currently in the Hessian of the probit link that uses numerical derivatives and is not very precise, which means that the parameters are well estimated but standard error can have numerical noise in GLM-Probit.

**update**
Two changes in statsmodels 0.12.2:
Probit now raises exception if response is not integer valued, and
GLM Binomial with Probit link uses improved derivatives for Hessian with precision now similar to discrete Probit.

Comment: As a follow up question, using `.fit_regularized()` means I can't seem to use `.summary()`. Do you know how to get a summary when using a regularized Binomial GLM?

Comment: summary is not available for GLM fit_regularized, mainly because inference for L1 penalized estimation is difficult. Standard errors and test statistics are not reliable for medium sized samples.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I'm not following but logistic classification is built on logistic regression (with the additional of some classification rule). I've used `Sklearn` before as well as `statsmodels`. A simple tutorial is provided [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/understanding-logistic-regression-python) if you need it. In short, you can use either

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
mod = sm.Logit(y, x)
result = logit_model.fit()
result.summary()

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
log_reg = LogisticRegression
mod2 = log_reg.fit(x, y)  # assuming x and y are colums from a pandas df
print(clf.coef_, clf.intercept_)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, sklearn's `LogisticRegression` requires target variables `y` to be 0/1. My values are continuous, between 0 and 1.

Comment: Same with statsmodels, I believe. But please - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I might be wrong about statsmodel. Currently investigating. I can't get `family=sm.families.Logit()` to work

Comment: I think the correct combination is `sm.GLM(..., link=sm.genmod.families.links.logit)`

Comment: Ahh, my apologies. I misread your question.  What are you trying to do? If you do not have a 0-1 dependent variable, logistic regression is  probably not going to be the correct choice.

Comment: I don't buy that. Why do you say that?

Comment: Without getting too far into Cross Validated territory, the model assumes that the dependent variable is drawn from some binomial process. The efficiency of the estimator is derived from that binomial distribution. If you break those assumptions, the model outcomes no longer hold true. That is why SKlearn prevents you from submitting a continuous variable. Such as a predictor does not work.

Comment: Why do I care about the efficiency of the estimator? All I'm saying is I'd like to find the maximum likelihood parameters w where my model is y = sigmoid(w^T x).

Comment: Then you don't really want logistic regression. If your data is sampled continuously between 0 and 1, maybe you want to check out some beta-regression. If you are really insisting on fitting a sigmoid function I guess you could use `curve_fit` from  `scipiy.optimize` , but you aren't going to get SEs from that.

Comment: Beta regression sounds appropriate. Is there a Python implementation you could add a demo of? If so, I'll accept your answer

Comment: What link function is used for beta regression?

Comment: Also, can you explain why a GLM with y = sigmoid(w^T x) is not a valid model for predicting probabilities y?

Comment: I posted on Cross Validated and had my question deleted.